# annotation line not visible in scatter chart in chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using chartjs library to render the chart i was using scatter chart and wanted  a reference line on the graph so i used charts-annotation to draw a line on the scatter charts but for some reason the line is not visible but i am able to see the scatter charts been drawn completely can anyone help.

HTML

```
<html>

<body>
  <div style="width: 75%">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
var chartData = {

  datasets: [
    {
      data:  [
        {
          x: 5,
          y: 4
        }, {
          x: 2,
          y: 14
        },
        {
          x: 4,
          y: 12
        },
        {
          x: 2,
          y: 10
        },
        {
          x: 3,
          y: 4
        },
        {
          x: 3,
          y: 5
        },
        {
          x: 3,
          y: 8
        },
        {
          x: 6,
          y: 12

        }]
    }
  ]
};

window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "scatter",
    data: chartData,
    options: {
      annotation: {
        annotations: [
          {
            type: "line",
            mode: "vertical",
            scaleID: "x-axis-0",
            value: '5',
            borderColor: "red",

          }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
};
```

i can see the scatter chart but no annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change scaleID: x-axis-0 to scaleID: x-axis-1

Comment: THANK YOU! I searched for this for so long; it seems like a simple thing to include in the annotation plugin documentation.

Comment: Wow - thanks so much - this took me hours to find too...